# Как правильно реализовать запрос поиска в JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

Я использую JPA для конструирования Rest API моего приложения.
Я хочу получить список вещей из items по полю cities_id и categories_id

У меня уже есть интерфейс, который позволяет мне использовать стандартные методы findAll и т.п.
Я попытался определить свой запрос через аннотацию Query.

```
public interface ItemsRepositories extends JpaRepository<Items, Long> {

    @Query("FROM items WHERE cities_id = ?1 AND categories_id = ?2")
    List<Items> findItemsByCityAndCategory(Cities city_id, Categories category_id);

}
```

И вызвать метод в контроллере:

```
@GetMapping("{city_id}/{category_id}")
    public List<Items> getItemByCityAndCategory(@PathVariable("city_id") Cities city, @PathVariable("category_id") Categories category) {
        return itemsRepositories.findItemsByCityAndCategory(city, category);
    }
```

Однако я получаю ошибку:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'itemsController' defined in file 
[C:\Users\home\Desktop\example\target\classes\demoapi\controllers\ItemsController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'itemsRepositories': Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List demoapi.repositories.ItemsRepositories.findItemsByCityAndCategory(demoapi.entities.Cities,demoapi.entities.Categories)!
```

Вопрос: как это правильно организовать со стороны JPA? Иными словами, я могу отказаться от этого решения и просто обработать список прямо в контроллере, отделив нужное от остального, но мне хотелось бы реализовать фильтрацию именно на стороне БД и получить только те записи, которые действительно нужны, используя JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка указывает, что не может создать bean класса ItemsRepositories, из за того, что у вас находится ошибка в запросе

Если вы используете не nave qury, то должны указывать класс который хотите получить с запроса

Это должно решить вашу проблему

```
@Query(value = "SELECT i FROM Items i WHERE i.cities_id = ?1 AND i.categories_id = ?2")
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо :)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста